Phonepe payment status issue
I am using PHP to check payment status but I am getting this error

{"message":"Bad Request - Api Mapping Not Found"}

function checkstatus() {
    global $MID, $txnid, $baseUrl, $saltkey, $keyindex;

    $merchantId = $MID;
    $transactionId = $txnid;

    $url = $baseUrl . '/v1/transaction/' . $merchantId . '/' . $transactionId . '/status';

    // for Sha256 calculation
    $api_saltkey = $saltkey;
    $str_forSha256 = '/v1/transaction/' . $merchantId . '/' . $transactionId . '/status' .     $api_saltkey;
    $sha_value = hash('sha256', $str_forSha256);
    $x_verify = $sha_value . '###' . $keyindex;

    $headers = array(
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "X-VERIFY: $x_verify"
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $res = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $res;
}

checkstatus()

I reviewed the PhonePe API documentation and developed the code accordingly. Now, I am looking to obtain the transaction status as the solution.

Any reason you don't use the ready-made SDK for PHP? https://developer.phonepe.com/v1/reference/pg-php-sdk

P.S. Please provide a link to the documentation of the specific API endpoint you are trying to call.

Yes, I am a beginner so I don't know how to set SDK in PHP on Hostinger. that's why I used to like that.... can you help me to reproduce this issue using an HTTP call? thanks

https://developer.phonepe.com/v2/reference/check-payment-status -- you can use this link

I don't know how to set SDK in PHP on Hostinger...you just upload the files there, like all your other PHP files in your website. If you have set up the SDK in your local development environment, when you're testing your code, then the PHP files from it will become part of your PHP website. Then you can upload it to the hosting environment the same way you upload all your other files. (If you are doing all your work directly in the hosted server, without testing locally first, then that is a more fundamental problem in your development process which you need to fix first).

(I would also point out that, while the install instructions for the SDK talk about using Composer, that is only a convenience feature, and not an absolute requirement. Composer just simplifies the process of installing libraries into your application. You always have the option to simply download the files manually from the provider, and integrate them yourself. It's just that this is sometimes a tricky process, especially if the library you want also depends on other libraries which you then need to install manually as well. Nonetheless, that option is always available to you.)

If you use the SDK then you should be able to check the transaction status as per https://developer.phonepe.com/v1/reference/php-pg-check-status, without having to worry about the small details of building the HTTP request

Anyway, if you want to carry on using cURL for now, I would point out that the documentation link you've provided states that the endpoint URL is https://mercury-t2.phonepe.com/v3/transaction/%7BmerchantId%7D/%7BtransactionId%7D/status. But in your code you are using v1/transaction... So maybe you simply have the wrong URL?
